# Running server for Ionic 2 app on Production

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

In dev/test environment, Ionic 2 app can be run using 'ionic serve'. However, when I deploy to i.e. Google Play or Apple Store does it need a special service to run the app to be able to fetch data from firebase?

Is it an additional service/hosting I need to purchase or it's taken care by the deployment and will just work when users download my app?

I can't find documentation on this. How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You don't need to do any additional things for the firebase backend.B'cose firebase is a cloud-based platform.If you set all the settings properly before publishing it to google paly or Apple store then all will work when someone will install the app.In other words, if an app is working fine on the dev environment then it will work when you'll publish it too.B'cos you're using the same cloud-based firebase environment.

*Note:*

You can start Firebase for free.But when your app is scaled worldwide to millions of users then you have to pay only for what you use.

You can see [**Firebase Pricing plan here**](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

Comment: Ok, so the app once is installed it won't have to run any nodejs server on client mobile device to fetch the data from firebase. Great!